# Need to use legacy PLSQL with DBLink call, in an XA transaction, and can not use shared connection

Tags: oracle, jakarta-ee, distributed-transactions, dblink, xa

I have an Oracle PLSQL program in database A, that select's data from other database B through a DBLink. I call the PLSQL program from a Java EE application. Till now, it all works fine. Database B is out out my scope, it belongs to an external provider.

Now I have to upgrade the Java EE application, to use another Java EE application (invoke EJB), so I need an XA data-source to manage distributed transaction. It then give's the "ORA-24777: use of non-migratable database link not allowed" error. I've searched and one solution is to connect to B through an MTS (shared) conection dblink. I can not change the DBLink to shared connection (because of customer restrictions).

Is there a way to tell Oracle in database A, that the DBLink is for select (read only data) so it's not necesary to propagate the distributed transaction to database B?
I tried defining an AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION, and seting READ ONLY TRANSACTION, but doesn't work. Also tried defining READ ONLY views for the remote tables, doesn't work

There are other possible solutions that I can not apply, like having a materialized view in A, reading data from B (external provider does'nt allow that).

Both databases are ORacle 11g Release 11.2.0.2.0

Comment: AFAIK, creating a local materialized view can not be (technically) blocked by an external provider. Or is it some kind of contractual agreement like "thou shall not create materialized views"?

Comment: It's something like that, is an "external provider", but in fact is the same customer (relative big customer for our country, with various DataCenters), and is the customer that doesn't allow us to create MVs, in order not to distribute data.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've seen this error before, and the way I think I got around it was to create a non xa data source because it was not necessary to propagate the transaction to the remote db since I was not changing data on the remote database.  And if you started off in a distributed transaction you should still be able to use the non-xa connection at the tail end if you can construct the execution path of the transaction to use this non-xa last (non-xa can commit as long as it's the last commit).  I read elsewhere the other solution is to create a shared db link.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Sadly, I can't isolate in a different connection (non-XA) the call to the DBLink, from the rest of the procedure, that needs XA. (In fact I can, but it would be too expensive and risky).